# Rigify fails automtic weight, ..ok but on which bone?

Tags: rigify

Well i used rigify quite often over the years, and so its not something I get into problems with usually.
Sometimes though rigify fails, is there is a log option to see which bone had problem ?
Or ideas on how to add such functionality to the rigify script?

Comment: It's not part of the rigify script.  It's part of the autoweight functionality built into Blender (which is probably C, not Python.)

Comment: As a general rule of thumb, if something in Blender gives an error message and you want more information, you can try checking the console (`Window` > `Toggle System Console`). I don't know what information it gives for this kind of error, but it might be helpful.

Comment: just checked the error its the same in the console, it has to be fixed in C then